# call unix sql script on windows using java program on windows

Tags: sql, windows, unix

I have a sql script on unix. I want to call it in a java program running on Windows. I don't have Oracle installed on my Windows. Is there any method to call script in java program from unix server and also see the output on cmd?

Comment: What exactly is "*a SQL script on Unix*"? A SQL script is run against a database, and it doesn't matter where that database is located as long as you have a SQL client to run it.

Comment: Why don't you connect to Unix Box using Putty or any other SSH terminal and execute the command directly?

Comment: i have connected it using putty but i want to execute it in a java program

Comment: i have oracle on unix environment

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install [SQL*Plus with Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) on your windows machine and use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` to execute `sqlplus.exe` and feed your SQL script to it.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the Statements with JDBC.